# Удалить первые два символа в каждом слове длиннее заданной величины

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

есть у меня строка на входе, и в ней нужно удалить первые два символа у слов, длина которых больше 4

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
String content = getInput("part1.txt");

}
public static String getInput(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "cp1251");
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            sb.append(scanner.nextLine()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        scanner.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

как это можно сделать?
на входе

```
When I was younger,
So much younger
than today
```

на выходе

```
en I was unger,
So ch unger
an day
```

Comment: Каким образом это получилось на выходе? `So ch unger`

Comment: @tym32167 это должен быть такой вывод

Comment: @tym32167 тут вроде как регулярные выражения должны использоваться, но не умею ими пользоваться

Comment: Как этот вывод получился то? Вы пишете, что надо удалить первый символы, а в примере удаляете символы из середки.

Comment: @tym32167 так там же написано, что надо удалить первые два символа в слове, длина которого больше 4

Comment: Там написано про строку, а не слово. Но я понял теперь что вы делаете.

Comment: @tym32167 каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Ну можно кодом или регулярками. Я регулярки не люблю, я бы кодом сделал. Но вам надо быть более конкретным, что именно вы считаете словом? `Д'Артаньян`, `Салтыков-Щедрин`, `01.02.2010` - что тут является словами и какой длины? Пунктуацию вы считаете частью слова?

Comment: @tym32167 ну первые два слова считается словом, 3 пример нет. ну допустим что считается.

Comment: `ну допустим что считается` вы же понимаете, что если в одном случае точка разделяет предложения, а во втором является частью слова, то это делает вашу задачу в разы сложнее. Давайте без допущений, укажите в вопросе все требования, что у вас есть, и как вы сами прбовали это решить.

Comment: @tym32167 я пробовал разбить текст с помощью split(), далее в словах которые имеют длину более 4, выделить подстроку substring(2), но из-за того, что я сплитил пробелом, у меня пропускало первые слова, и посоветовали использовать регулярку

Comment: @tym32167 там всё чуть проще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагаю, что это какая-то практическая задачка, и особого внимания ко входным данным не требует. Чуток видоизменил ваш метод, при необходимости можно внести дополнения в переменную `regex`

```
public static String getInput(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String regex = "([A-Za-z]+)[^A-Za-z]+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "cp1251")) {
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator();

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String block = matcher.group();
                String word = block.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
                sb.append((word.length() >= 4 ? block.substring(2) : block));
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: а как мне сделать так , чтобы слова на кириллице тоже считывало корректно?

Comment: как советовали, в regex можно добавить нужные условия. Или же для всех языков подходящий вариант - `regex = "([\\p{L}]+)[^\\p{L}]+";`. Будьте внимательны  с кодировкой, если увидите каракули для кириллицы, то скорее всего стоит заменить "cp1251" на что-нибудь другое

Answer (score 0):

Находит слова длины 4+, удаляете в них найденную группу:

```
([\w'-][\w'-])[\w'-][\w'-]+
```

Использованы именно такие определения символов, а не просто `\w`, исходя из комментариев. Нужны ещё какие-то символы — добавляйте.

Тест https://regexr.com/593a5

> **When** I was **younger**,
>
> So **much** **younger**
>
> **than** **today**
>
> **wbtb** **wtombotb** wrb **omwb**    **wtbombr**   **wtomo**